# How to get an element of a list by specifying element position as list?

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

How can I retrieve an element of a list, specifying the position of the desired element as another list? For instance, I like to get `list[[2,1]]` but all I have is `pos = {2,1}`. I want something like `list[[pos]]` or `list@@pos` and not `list[[pos[[1]],pos[[2]]]]` or `Extract[list,pos]` (unless there is a shorhand for `Extract`).

Comment: `list[[##]]&@@pos`.

Comment: `Extract[list, {2,1}]`. Why not use this one?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, doesn't work for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: What about `Part[list, #1, #2]&@@pos`?

Comment: I mean, a "shorthand" for `Extract` could be `list~Extract~pos`.

Comment: I mean, a "shorthand" for `Extract` could be `list~Extract~pos`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov, I wish you wrote this as an answer. But thank you anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[42]; m = RandomInteger[10, {4, 2}]
```

> `{{6, 0}, {8, 2}, {0, 0}}`

```
m[[##]] & @@ {2, 1}
```

> `8`